# Locked Array Com Exception

Tags: c#, arrays, multithreading, com, locking

I've got a problem with using arrays in an API method in a Thread.
Locking the arrays didn't work.

```
Thread thrCreate = new Thread(createThread);
thrCreate.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
thrCreate.Start();

private void createThread()
{
    IEdmAddCustomRefs2 pdmRefs = (IEdmAddCustomRefs2)vault2.CreateUtility(EdmUtility.EdmUtil_AddCustomRefs);

    IEdmFile5 pdmRefFile = (IEdmFile5)pdmResult;        

    int[] iRefCount = new int[1];
    iRefCount[0] = 1;

    string[] strRefPath = new string[1];
    strRefPath[0] = strPDFPath + strSerName + ".pdf";

    lock (strRefPath)
    {
        lock (iRefCount)
        {
            pdmRefs.AddReferencesPath2(pdmRefFile.ID, ref strRefPath, ref iRefCount);
        }
    }
}
```

COM Exception is called DISP_E_ARRAYISLOCKED.

Comment: A `lock` statement will not help here. The lock being referred to in the HRESULT's name is the locking of the COM array contained in a Variant.

Comment: The error basically indicates that running this code on a worker thread was not a good idea.  You'll have to ask SolidWorks what it is possible, but the expected response is "don't do that".

Comment: Within the implementation of `IEdmAddCustomRefs2` there is an safe array where the calls to [`SafeArrayLock`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221492(v=vs.85).aspx) exceed the calls to [`SafeArrayUnlock`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221246(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am now using the AddReferences method and I am not getting the Exception anymore.

Here is the updated code:

```
Thread thrCreate = new Thread(createThread);
thrCreate.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
thrCreate.Start();

private void createThread()
{
    IEdmAddCustomRefs2 pdmRefs = (IEdmAddCustomRefs2)vault2.CreateUtility(EdmUtility.EdmUtil_AddCustomRefs);

    IEdmFile5 pdmRefFile = (IEdmFile5)pdmResult;        

    string[] strRefPath = new string[1];
    strRefPath[0] = strPDFPath + strSerName + ".pdf";

    pdmRefs.AddReferencesPath(pdmRefFile.ID, ref strRefPath);
}
```